# How to state permisssion fields for request to Google.Apis.Drive.v3

Tags: asp.net-core, google-drive-api

Im trying to get EmailAddress field of the file permission. I know that calling library methods like this:

```
PermissionList permissions = service.Permissions.List(Id_file).Execute();
```

will return objects with only couple of fields, while others will be null, thus i have to create request with explicitly stated fields that i want. Here is what i did:

```
PermissionsResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Permissions.List(Id_file);
listRequest.Fields = "EmailAddress";
var perms1 = listRequest.Execute().Permissions;
```

But, it throws exception that EmailAddress field doesnt exist.
So, how do i get permission with non-null EmailAddress property?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found it myself:

```
listRequest.Fields = "permissions(emailAddress)";
```